# UNION ALL | Merge 2 queries that have the same column and table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to merge to queries together. This is a simple task that I do a lot, but this time I have something a little bizarre. The 2 queries I'm merging are from the same table and the same column.

Here is a basic concept of my original table:

```
|id|content|
 0 | a
 1 | b
 2 | c
 3 | d
```

I want my query to return everything once. Then again where I selected it. So `SELECT * FROM 'my_table'` and `SELECT * FROM 'my_table WHERE id IN (1,2)` I want it to return something like this.

```
a
b
a
b
c
d
```

**Edit:** @dnoeth commented the right answer. I didn't read it right the first time though.

Comment: `1 st SELECT UNION ALL 2nd SELECT`

Comment: Here is what i'm doing now. But it doesn't work. `$posts = Posts::where('id','>=',0)->union($reposts)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. I just didn't know how to word was I was looking for.

What I needed to do was unite 2 queries on the same table.
You do this by simply using **UNION ALL** instead of union

So here is an example in **mysql**.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

Then if you are using **Laravel**'s eloquent like I am use this.

```
$query = Class::whereIn('id', $array);
Class::where('id','>=',0)->unionAll($query)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you're not really precise on what the result should be, you might do like this:

```
select t1.val
from tableT t1
join tableT t2 on t1.id=t2.id or t1.id+1=t2.id
where t1.id<=2 and t2.id<=2 or t1.id>=3
```

Should yield:

```
a
b
b
c
c
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the clause UNION, you can "join" several SELECTs with the only restiction that they have same result columns. Your example will be:

```
(SELECT * FROM 'my_table')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM 'my_table WHERE id IN (1,2))
```

And you will get:

```
|id|content|
 0 | a
 1 | b
 2 | c
 3 | d
 1 | b
 2 | c
```

More details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

PS:

The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Comment: I don't know if this works in Mysql, but when I used this in Laravel it threw an error. I used UNION ALL and it worked.

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle for this?

Comment: The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.